# Nested Dictionary with bytes

Tags: python, dictionary, byte

I have a nested dictionary with the letter b at the beginning of it. How do I pull out the amounts?

```
b'{"annual":{"fica":{"amount":76500},"federal":{"amount":331249.5},"state":{"amount":null}}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a dictionary; you have a byte string that contains JSON.

```
import json
s = b'{"annual":{"fica":{"amount":76500},"federal":{"amount":331249.5},"state":{"amount":null}}}'
d = json.loads(s)        # parse the JSON
d                        # now it's a dictionary
# => {'annual': {'fica': {'amount': 76500}, 'federal': {'amount': 331249.5}, 'state': {'amount': None}}}
d['annual']['fica']['amount']
# => 76500
```

Comment: Note that this is a new Python 3 type. For more info see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects